# Gave Up Waiting For Root Device When Booting, but UUID Matches

Tags: boot, grub2

I am getting a "gave up waiting for root device" error message whent trying to boot into Ubuntu. Live CD works perfectly, and I've tried Running the Boot Repair with no success, it seemed to have failed.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8077003/

I've checked the GRUB configuration (through Grub Customizer), and it looks to be booting to the right device. The UUID it's trying to boot to is f74a304c-58c9-4689-be48-b95b5a84346a which matches the configuration.

Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the BIOS disk enumeration differs from grub's.  If you get to a grub prompt, try looking at the hd1 disk and see if it is the one you expect (check avail partitions with the tab completion is one easy way).  type set root=(hd1,  TAB   and the partitions will be listed.  If you are getting the other disk, edit the hd1 s to hd0 s, try the boot with F10 or crtl X.  If that's the issue, you can edit all the hds in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file, but be ready to do that each time you update kernels.  I have not seen hard disks get mixed up like that, but USB disks are subject to that, and the BIOS enumeration is not even consistent, but changes sometimes -- maybe a timing issue.

Comment: even if I try and set the root device I still have the same problem. It's saying it can't find the UUID.                       http://imgur.com/HD9Rvd9